# How does C exactly run?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

I just realized when I define a function in C and use it, I can either use it and define the function later or define it and use it later. For example,

```
int mult (int x, int y)
{
  return x * y;
}

int main()
{
  int x;
  int y;
  scanf( "%d", &x );
  scanf( "%d", &y );
  printf( "The product of your two numbers is %d\n", mult( x, y ) );
}
```

and

```
int main()
    {
      int x;
      int y;
      scanf( "%d", &x );
      scanf( "%d", &y );
      printf( "The product of your two numbers is %d\n", mult( x, y ) );
    }   

int mult (int x, int y)
    {
      return x * y;
    }
```

will both run just fine. However, in Python, the second code will fail since it requires `mult(x,y)` to be defined before you can use it and Python executes from top to bottom(as far as I know). Obviously, that can't be the case in C since the second one runs just fine. So how does C code actually flow?

Comment: You need to conceptualize the difference between source code compilation and runtime behavior.

Comment: Taking another approach: Programming is about structures. The linear order of source code fragments is an artefact of 'writing down stuff'. So you wouldn't expect an intrinsic dependency between both (though some 'settings' [ie. programming languages] may enforce it). Some introductory text on compilers might interest you.

Comment: Your question body is well formulated, but the title suggests a different question. Something like "Is the order of function definitions important in C" would fit better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the second code is not valid C, strictly speaking.

It uses your compiler's flexibility to allow an implicit declaration of a function, which has been disallowed in C standard.

The `C11` standatd explicitly mentions the *exclusion* in the "Foreword",

> 7. Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> ...
>
> - remove implicit function declaration

You have to either

- [Forward declare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) the function.
- Define the function before it's usage (like snippet 1).

Enable the warning in your compiler and your compiler should produce some warning message to let you know about this *problem*.

Comment: Ah I see, so if I put int mult(int x, int y); in the start of the second code (and define exactly what it does later) it'll be fine in C standard as well, is this correct?

Comment: @J.Shim yes that is called forward deceleration and is legal, and often how it's done.

Comment: @Fredrik Alright, that still leaves me with a question. When I do the forward declaration, I'd have A(forward declaration) -> B(where I use the function) -> C(where I define what the function from A actually does), so will it look for C when it sees A and then come back for B? And you said this is "often how it's done". Why would you do it this way instead of defining the entire function first?

Comment: @J.Shim Exactly how the compiler does it I can't answer I'm afraid, outside my comfort zone. About the other part though, usually you have forward declarations declared in a .h file and the implementation in a .c file. However if you have local/private functions you have the forward declaration in the same file, imagine if you had 20 local functions, if you didn't forward declare them you would have to sort them in the order they are used.

Comment: @J.Shim The short answer is - compiler needs to know about the function prototype -  the supplied argument type & count and the return type. If it gets to see a prototype, it is OK with going ahead. If it does not know about the prototype (yet) and get to see a function call - it has no idea of the function details - it can still go ahead to the linking stage all right - but without having any idea on the function properties - which may create problems later.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, routines should be *declared* before they are used, although they do not need to be *defined* before they are used. Additionally, older versions of C allowed some implicit declaration of routines, and some compilers still do, although this is largely archaic now.

As to how C is able to support the calling of functions before they are defined, C programs are first *translated* into some executable format, after which a program is *executed*.

During translation, a C compiler reads, analyzes, and processes the entire program. Any references to functions that have not yet been defined are recorded as things that need to be resolved in the program. In the process of preparing a final executable file, a linker goes through all of the processed data, finds the function definitions, and resolves the references by inserting the addresses (or other information) of the called routines.

Most commonly, a C compiler translates source code into an object module. The object module contains machine-language instructions for the program. It also contains any data for the program that is defined in the source code, and it contains information about unresolved references that the compiler found while analyzing the source code. Multiple source files may be translated separately into multiple object modules. Sometimes these translations are done by different people at different times. A company might produce a software library which is the result of translating their source files into object modules and packaging them into a library file. Then a software developer would compile their own source files and link the resulting object modules with the object modules in the library.

Multiple object modules can be linked together to make an executable file. This is a file that the operating system is able to load into memory and execute.

Answer (score 0):

For second code you should use forward declaration. That means first declare the function so that compiler will know you will be using this function. For now your code is executed as per C compiler flexibility.

Python compiler is not flexible enough so it will fail to compile.

Comment: I'd imagine this has something to do with Python using an *interpreter* rather than a *compiler*, no?

Comment: First python is compiled into byte code and then byte code is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You said both the codes work just fine. Well, it doesn't. The second snippet will show an error in my compiler and if it does compile correctly, it should not be used.

- It voids C regulations.
- Declaring functions before is helpful when too many user defined functions are needed.